# Nuget.exe pack times out

Tags: nuget, f#-fake

As part of the build process, it packages with `NuGet` and pushes to NuGet server. All was OK, but after updating the `NuGet` version to the latest it just hangs there on the `pack` command.
I'm using F#Fake for the build process, and after quite a long period the `nuget.exe pack` command just times out:

```
Running build failed.
Error:
System.Exception: Process E:\Builds\projectName\build\tools\nuget\nuget.exe pack -Symbols -Version 1.0.0.0-pre -OutputDirectory "E:\Builds\projectName\build\package\out" "E:\Builds\projectName\build\package\tmp\template.nuspec" -NoPackageAnalysis    timed out.
   at Fake.NuGetHelper.NuGet(FSharpFunc`2 setParams, String nuspecOrProjectFile) in D:\code\FAKE\src\app\FakeLib\NuGet\NugetHelper.fs:line 423
   at FSI_0005.Build.clo@163-25.Invoke(Unit _arg10)
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in D:\code\FAKE\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 626
```

**Update:**
The same command directly without `Fake`'s wrapping, hangs there for around 20 mins on the below lines:

```
NuGet Version: 4.4.1.4656
Attempting to build package from 'template.nuspec'.
```

Finally it does create the package, but never used to be that long.
I've tested with `NuGet v2.8.6` and same operation takes seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I've discovered that any of the 4+ versions of a NuGet have the problem with taking ages to create a package.

I've stopped on v3.5.0, where packaging timings are OK.

However it had [another unexpected/frustrating change](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3050), where it forces the version normalization, i.e. if requested to pack with 1.0.123.0, the nuspec is generated with 1.0.123 skipping the last 0.
**Update**: apparently the version normalization is a [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/package-versioning) breaking change from version 3.4 and above.